# Optimization on Binomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-optimization

Suppose we are given integers $1\leq r\leq N$, we want to study the following
$$
\max_{m_0+m_1=N,m_0,m_1\geq 1}\max_j  \tbinom {m_0}{j}\tbinom {m_1}{r-j}.
$$

$N$ is very large, for instance $N\geq 5000$.

I guess it is

$$
\tbinom {N-1}{r}.
$$

Comment: No, $\binom{N-1}{r-1}$ is bigger if $r\ge N/2$.

Comment: @Brendan Thanks, then what can we say about the maximum value?

Comment: For fixed $m_0+m_1=N$, the maximum over $j$ is at least $\frac{\binom{N}{r}}{1+\min(r,m_0,m_1)}$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Thanks, I understand your argument, but I indeed would like to obtain upper bound.